# iOS Swift 5 Change device orientation manually

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS swift 5 project I need to support multiple device orientations in only one scene.

I have the following requirements:

- If device is rotated, device orientation should not be changed.
- If button is tapped, device orientation should be changed (left
  rotation)

This means that in only one `UIViewController` user should be able to change device orientation manually by tapping on a button, but rotating the device should not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this is by setting your supported orientation on the `AppDelegate` [(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623107-application)

Create a local variable there

```
var orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
```

and then return that variable as supported orientation

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return orientation
    }
```

on the `ViewController` that you want to rotate with a touch of a button, you can change the supported orientation on the app delegate and than force the device orientation to change so that the view is rotated

```
    private func changeSupportedOrientation() {
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        switch delegate.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            delegate.orientation = .landscapeLeft
        default:
            delegate.orientation = .portrait
        }
    }

    @IBAction func rotateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        changeSupportedOrientation()
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIDeviceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        default:
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
```

this will force the orientation of the device to change and then rotate your view. If you tap on the button again the orientation will be back to `.portrait`

Please be careful of using this as you need to really consider your navigation stack to make sure that only the top of the navigation stack support rotation and can only be pop from the navigation stack after the orientation is set back to the original which is `.portrait` only.